# PHP 7 trying to destroy resource obtained from C-extension produces segfault

Tags: segmentation-fault, destructor, php-extension, php-7.2

Have written a C-extension for PHP 5 and now am upgrading it to PHP 7.

I have modified all API calls as per new demands from zend framework so that the code compiles.
Placed my .so file in the extension location and php-fpm service starts operation.

Basically I request for a custom hashtable(legacy code) from within my C extension, convert it to a zval and use it within php and then as the scope ends, its destructor should be called but there is ome problem here and we see a segmentation fault.

Here is my code C - file:

```
static int le_myResource;
#define le_myResource_name  "a myResource resource"

void myResource_destruction_handler(zval *rsrc TSRMLS_DC)
{
    myResource *d = (myResource *)zend_fetch_resource(Z_RES_P(rsrc), le_myResource_name, le_myResource);
    myResource_free(d);
}

rsrc_dtor_func_t myResource_destruction_handler;
le_myResource = zend_register_list_destructors_ex(myResource_destruction_handler, NULL, le_myResource_name, module_number);

ZEND_FUNCTION(myhash_new)
{
    myResource *d;
    d = myHash_new(); // my legacy project code returning a hash. The same way it returned to php5

    RETURN_RES(zend_register_resource(d, le_myResource));
}
```

And this is the calling PHP file

```
<?php
class dbd {

    function query()
    {
        $reply = myhash_new()
        // use $reply
        // print statement here works

    }// this is where the problem occurs
}
?>
```

The gdb stacktrace shows the below:

```
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `php-fpm: pool www                                                             '.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000900000000 in ?? ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install ironwood-php-7.2.3.bfeature.B.88927_upgrade_to_php7-r20180313172814.9f25293.bLOCAL.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000900000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000170000003e in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000001fb3250 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000000003 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007fbbff29e160 in ?? ()
#5  0x000000000079f8fa in list_entry_destructor ()
#6  0x00000000007971ba in zend_hash_index_del ()
#7  0x000000000084168f in zend_leave_helper_SPEC ()
#8  0x00000000007d4228 in execute_ex ()
#9  0x0000000000841327 in zend_execute ()
#10 0x0000000000787094 in zend_execute_scripts ()
#11 0x000000000071300e in php_execute_script ()
#12 0x000000000084ebfe in main ()
```

Am not sure as to how can I control the memory that is generated from a third party library and then avoid it being corrupted.
The same piece worked with php5 earlier. Scanned a lot on the www but couldnt able to crack it. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. it was because of using **rsrc_dtor_func_t** for my destructor function. I had compilation issues earlier when I had not used the above keyword.

Also **replaced zval* to zend_resource*** in myResource_destruction_handler and changed function to **static void** myResource_destruction_handler() which solved all my issues.

As of now I am not running into destruction level crashes.